# ipython notebook lost after deleting a folder

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

My ipython notebook was in a given folder that I deleted from the terminal in the same time, and he get lost.
doing `pwd` or `cd` gives me :

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.


Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.
```

How can I solve this without restartint the kernel ? (which I guess will solve the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

```
import os
os.chdir("/Full/path/from/root/to/my/existing/folder")
```